# lotusscript put code in view of column mail database

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

It's possible to get in view of column mail database, (of course if is) @Author department (or somthig other information from adress book/ldap)? Formula? Domnio 8.53

Answer (score 1):

No it is unfortunately NOT possible: @DbColumn and @Dblookup do not work in column formulas. If you need to display that information, you need to write it into the document (and probably check the validity of that i formation on a regular basis and refresh if necessary).

A view always shows documents. And these documents have items that store the information. You can only show information in the view that is stored in exactly this document that is shown. You can in NO WAY display data from any other document in the same row of the view not even from another document of the same type.

Your maifile e.g. contains documents of type "memo". They have information about the mail (from whom, sent to who, when, subject, body, etc...).
Your mailfile can also containt documents of type "contact". They have information about contact persons (first name, last name, phone number, department, etc...)

There is NO WAY to show information from a contact in a row of a view that shows a memo document. NO WAY.

Comment: it's not possible to use ldapserach in formula?

Comment: This is a complete different question. But the answer is the same: no, its not possible

Comment: [link](https://iv.pl/image/GriX2Jw)  I still don't belive, maybe lotussearch execute ?

Comment: Please believe it. Torsten is correct. A design decision was made a very, very long time ago to not allow any @formula functions in view formulas if they are dependent on data that is external to the view's selected documents. This was done because the indexer cannot keep track of external dependencies. The views would either be showing information that can be out-of-date, or else the formulas would have to be re-executed every time the view is displayed. There would be a big performance hit either way. In modern times, this might be able to be changed, but it hasn't been.

Comment: And what you're seeing in that image that you linked is the Department field on some form or subform in the mail file itself. It is not linked to the address book. I don't know which form it's on, but I guarantee it's in there somewhere - or it was at least in a form or subform in a previous version of the mail template. That list comes from something called the "UNC Table" which contains entries for every field on every form and subform.

Comment: You can synchronize contacts into your mailfile (for use with Traveler or iNotes). Department is in the Contacts- Form that is used to display that synchronized contacts. And: I work with Notes/Domino since 1995 (since 2001 as Consultant), I KNOW it.

Comment: Torsten I'm sorry, I don't dare your huge knowledge. [link](https://iv.pl/image/Gri7gap) Yes, it work's in Contacs view but still not in $inbox

Comment: So whats wrong with the image? Yes, this view shows the contacts view in a mailfile... and the contacts there contain a department field... But this item is stored in the document and not looked up by the view...

Comment: [link](https://iv.pl/image/Gri7x5m) in mail folder still missing this info.

Comment: Yes, thats what I told you: It is NOT POSSIBLE. The information is in the contact documents. But you display memo- documents that do not have the information. And a Lookup IS NOT POSSIBLE.